# What is Folktale's Future for?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, folktale

### Background

I am reading every inch of the docs and trying to learn about Folktale as much as I can.
Recently, I decide to try [`Future`](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.1.0/en/folktale.concurrency.future.html).

### Do we need a Future?

Now while I understand the difference between `Task` and `Promise` and between `Task` and `Future` ( support for cancellation ) it is not clear to me the difference between `Future` and `Promise`.

Why would I ever want to use a `Future` instead of a `Promise` ? What benefits would I have?
Well, you can say: "This way you actually have a monad, instead of a sorry excuse for a monad".

And that is a fine argument on it's own but... having in mind I always need to convert from Promise to something else ( to future ) and that the `Future`'s API is pretty much the same, it is not clear to me, as someone new, why I should care about `Future` at all.

### Code sample

Lets assume I have this function, where `request` is a function that makes a request and returns some results.

`extractRequestInfo` is a function that extracts data from the response object.
If something fails, I `catch` the error and return an object with all the data, the badId and the error.

```
const requestFruit = request => data =>
    request( data )
        .then( extractRequestInfo )
        .catch( error => ( { badId: prop( [ "Id" ], data ), error } ) );
```

Given that this is an HTTP request, I know I don't need a `Task` because there is no cancellation I can do here. So my options are `Promise` and `Future`.

### Questions

1. How would I use `Future` in this sample?
2. Since this is something that can fail, should I use `Result` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the response from the creator Quil:

> Future solves the same problem Promise does, so there isn't much of a
>   conceptual difference between the two. The difference is more in how
>   they solve the problem.
>
> Promises can either settle successfully or fail. In any transformation
>   you apply to a promise's value, errors thrown synchronously will be
>   implicitly caught and reject the promise as well. This is interesting
>   in async/await because you can handle these errors (synchronous and
>   asynchronous) in a similar way--you don't need to lift every
>   synchronous operation into a promise, because the runtime will do that
>   for you.
>
> The downside of this is that it's very easy to catch errors that you
>   didn't intend to, and have your system run in an inconsistent state. I
>   don't think you can do much with static analysis here either.
>
> Futures don't have that problem because nothing is lifted into a
>   future implicitly. If you want synchronous operations to use the
>   Future pipeline for handling errors, you have to put them there
>   explicitly. This gives you more control over error handling, and
>   uncaught errors will still crash the process as expected (avoiding
>   having your program run into inconsistent memory states for cases you
>   didn't predict), but it takes more effort to write programs this way.
>
> Other than that, if you consider Tasks, Futures model the eventual
>   value of a Task with a success case, a failure case, and a
>   cancellation case. Promises only have a success case and a failure
>   case, so cancellation is modelled as a special failure value. This
>   changes the idioms for handling cancellations a bit. It's possible for
>   code using promises to handle failures without being aware of this
>   special cancellation value, which may be a problem since this value
>   may easily be lost during these transformations.
>
> In codebases that mix promises and tasks, these problems are more
>   complicated because the implicit-lifting of errors that promises do is
>   not very compatible with the explicit-lifiting of errors that
>   tasks/futures expect (this can lead to problems like this one: #163).
>   Finding these bugs becomes a lot harder than if you had only promises
>   or only tasks/futures. Not sure what's the best way to handle these
>   cases yet.

For the original discussion:

https://github.com/origamitower/folktale/issues/200